# How to convert a MySQL `LIMIT` clause to a PostgreSQL `LIMIT` clause?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

An example MySQL query:

```
    SELECT message_id, message_text
    FROM messages
    LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I am getting this hint as a error:

```
HINT: Use separate LIMIT and OFFSET clauses.
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Compare the LIMIT syntax of [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

```
[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
```

to the one used by [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/queries-limit.html):

```
[LIMIT { number | ALL }] [OFFSET number]
```

This should give you enough information that you need to replace `LIMIT 0, 30` with `LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0`. (Note that the latter is also valid MySQL syntax).

Comment: Also notice that: "OFFSET 0 is the same as omitting the OFFSET clause" so you can also use "LIMIT 30"

Comment: Great ! Example - `select * from public.user limit 20 offset 20`

Comment: This is what makes Stackoverflow great: sure, it's all in the docs, but way easier if someone can pull it out there and put it in a nice concise answer :-)